# script to find which key belongs which IP address after finding all non matching elements in python?

Tags: python

I have two dictionaries which are present in a list & I have two lists likewise. These two lists I got from converting two JSON object to dictionaries & appending those dictionaries into two lists. These two JSON objects I got by providing two IP addresses in the command line prompt. That means I got all the non matching keys by using `set()`.

Code here:

```
first = dict(a=1, b=2)
second = dict(b=0, c=3)
for i in range(1):
    diff = set(first) ^ set(second)
    print diff
```

Right now I want to find which key belongs to which IP address?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for key in diff:
    if key in first:
        print 'First IP'
    elif key in second:
        print 'Second IP'
```